# Replace phone battery with power supply circuit BL-T5

Tags: batteries, android, mobile-phones

I have an old nexus phone LG e960 I'd like to use for a project permanently connected to mains .
The battery is long dead and it no longer charges. I've swapped it but the replacement didn't last long. Plugging usb cable with the battery in also does not allow a boot. You can get something on screen but shuts down mid boot.

I would like to take the battery out and replace it with some sort of permanent power supply to the phone so I guess the circuit needs to mimic the battery.

Battery is an LG BL-T5 3.8V

The battery connects to the phone with 4 pins and flex cable. But I believe 2 of those pins are connected so only 3 pins in reality.
The flex cable is labelled "v+ th v-"

**Do you know what the TH pin is** and what sort of circuit would I need to mimic its signal? Is it a simple resistance or a type of serial communication where a microcontroller is required?

Thank you for any pointers.

Pictures attached
[image: battery connection]

Answer (score 3):

The TH pin is most likely for a thermistor (temperature sensor) built in to the battery. Very common on lithium batteries like this, also common in power tools etc.

Most commonly as far as I know, the battery contains an NTC thermistor connected between the dedicated thermistor pin (TH in this case) and battery negative (V-).

I could only guess what the phone will do if this pin is unconnected. You can try without connecting it, worst that could happen is that the phone doesn't start.

If it doesn't start without the thermistor connected, you could replace it with a fixed resistor. Since you have the original battery, you could then measure resistance from the TH pin on the battery to the negative terminal, at room temperature. Then connect a resistor of similar value in its place.

Here is an image of how it is usually connected inside the battery:

[image: Battery internals]

Answer (score 2):

TH pin is a connection to a thermal sensor inside the battery pack - either a resistor (e.g. NTC) or a fancy 1-wire thing. The phone's internal circuitry uses it to measure the battery temperature for safety reasons. You can try to measure the resistance between TH pin and V- to see if there's really an NTC/PTC there.

As Klas-Kenny has stated in his answer, most of the time the phone does not need to read the temperature to start the device and you can use a fix resistor to trick the device. But first you should make sure that there's really a "resistive" sensing element.